# Android application as server and Web application as Client

Tags: android

Need to create the android emulator as a server and the web application as a client. Is it possible to invoke the application in the emulator from the web app client.

Comment: Is it only emulator and not phone?

Comment: I'm not sure if Google Cloud Messaging can help you.